# Connect Excel file with InDesign CC

Tags: javascript, excel, adobe-indesign

I'm working on a catalog and I would like to connect data (product code and it's price) from excel file with textbox or table inside InDesign. Inside InDesign textboxes are not in the same place/table.

Is there a way to do this?

For example, to add a listener to product code textbox in InDesign and when you write product code and click enter it finds matching product code inside excel file and then copies product price from excel file to product price textbox in InDesign.

Comment: Have you tried extendscript?

Comment: Using your example I would try to tag your text boxes, export exel to xml and import into InDesign to update the values, you might need extra xslt for the import. You can also try to use AppleScript/VBScript to search and get the value from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have regular catalogs to lay out, you should envision EasyCatalog. Although you can't achieve great stuff with scripting I am not sure it's worthy to spend time and efforts where existing tools can do the job in a blink ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way? Yes. One way: Import the spreadsheet into a text frame on the pasteboard then use indesign's scripting api to transfer values from spread sheet to text on the page. Consider using tags to mark price text and product codes to make them easier for the script to find.